# Visa requirement? Germany visit: UK citizen & South African wife

Tags: visas, germany, south-african-citizens

I hope someone can help!  We intend going to Germany over Christmas, but there is the big question of VISA??  My wife is South African, so is my 22 year old daughter, I am a UK citizen.  Leaving from Munich airport three years ago the immigration officer said that wife and children actually (as a family travelling with me) do not need visas.  The Germany Embassy in London is a bit ambiguous about this fact and still issued us with a visa (we got one 'just in case' last April) without confirming what the immigration officer said.  EU regulation 2004/38/EC states that a non-eu spouse can travel without visa, but what my (now 22 year old) daughter?

Answer (score 3):

The regulation as it is explained on the [Finland's Embassy UK site](http://www.finemb.org.uk/public/default.aspx?nodeid=37221&contentlan=2&culture=en-GB#Family_members_of_EEA_nationals):

> According to the EU Directive 38/2004 (Art. 2) family members of EEA nationals who are in possession of a British residence permit named "Residence Card of a Family Member of an EEA National" do not need a visa for visits up to 90 days in the Schengen area if they are joining or travelling with the EEA national. Residence card should be endorsed in your valid passport.

So if your wife and daughter have the UK residence card they can visit without a visa.